# How to fix VBA runtime error 70 permission denied

Tags: excel, permissions

I am trying to fill a combo box in Excel, based on values from a column of data on another worksheet.  I am getting the Runtime 70 permission denied error.  Any help would be appreciated. (.AddItem - throws the error)

```
Sub Fill_Combo()
  'Turn on the enabling of events in Excel, if it is not already on.
  Application.EnableEvents = True
' Create a new worksheet object to reference
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim rg As Range
  Dim cmb As ComboBox
  Dim strVal As String
'Set the new worksheet object to the worksheet you want to reference.
  Set ws = Workbooks("Test 6043 v3.xlsm").Worksheets("Ending Balances")
  Set rg = ws.Range("G1")
  Set cmb = Workbooks("Test 6043 v3.xlsm").Worksheets("Reconciliation").cmbBox2

'Reference the combobox and start adding items to it.
'With Workbooks("Test 6043 v3.xlsm").Worksheets("Reconciliation").cmbBox2
    'First, clear the combobox if there is anything in it.
    '.Clear
    'Check to see whether G1 on the Ending Balances sheet is empty.
    If IsEmpty(rg.Value) Then
        'If it is then...
        Do
            'Move down by one row
            Set rg = rg.Offset(1, 0)
            'Keep doing this until a non-empty row is found
        Loop Until (Not (IsEmpty(rg.Value)))
        'Then, once one range (cell) is found that is non-empty
        Do
            strVal = rg.Value
            With cmb
                'Add its value to the combo box.
                **.AddItem strVal**
                'Keep looping and add these values in Column G until the first non-empty row is found,again.
            End With
            'Move down by another row
            Set rg = rg.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop Until (IsEmpty(rg.Value))
    Else
```

Comment: Any luck? I'm having a similar issue with word.

Answer (score 1):

The combobox was created in design mode in Excel.  Its "ListFillRange" property was set to a range of cell values on another sheet.  Once I deleted its ListFillRange property and removed everything from that property of the combo box, I no longer saw this error come up.  Code compiles and seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers here on StackOverflow about this VB Error. Each answer or situation is unique in reality - although each existing answer states a different potential root cause (file permissions, folder permissions, name reuse, ranges, etc).

I would recommend narrowing down the root-cause by double clicking on the side of the stating function/code in order to mark a breakpoinnt (looks like a red dot) (Alternatively, you can right click on the line of the code - Select the `Toggle` and then `Breakpoint`).

Next, run your code, and it will stop in your breakpoint. You can then Step-Into/Over/Out your code and essentially find the line of code that is responsible for throwing your error code. (Step Into is `F8`, Step over is `Shift+F8` ((Go To the `Debug` top menu to see more options)))

Once you identified the responsible line of code - you can start looking further.

In my case scenario, I was using a protected variable name "Date" (look into [variable names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/index)). Once I renamed it to something else, the problem was fixed.